# Pivot a longer dataframe to wide with multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, wide-format-data

I have a dataframe with 1000+ rows in a long format. I need to pivot into wider format using the ID as the pivoter.  Pivoting it using pivot_wider only returns values in the first column, but not all of the columns.

Here is my code:

```
#Test data
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(TRCC1, TRCC1, DNRC1, ILAC1),
  AJ_Vol = c(14.454166, 14.976905, 11.344002, 5.673755)
)


# Use spread to pivot the dataframe
wide_df <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = ID, values_from = AJ_Vol, values_fn =  list(AJ_Vol = list))
```

This what the data looks like in long.
head(wide_df,100)

|  | ID | AJ_Vol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | TRCC1 | 14.454166 |
| 22 | TRCC1 | 14.976905 |
| 46 | DNRC1 | 11.344002 |
| 86 | ILAC1 | 5.673755 |

Here is what I want it to look like:

| TRCC1 | DNRC1 | ILAC1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14.454166 | 11.344002 | 5.673755 |
| 14.976905 |  |  |

Comment: … but you have only one column in addition to your id column. Your problem is not clear to me.

Comment: You have 2 `ID` == `"TRCC1"` rows in `df` and therefore 2 identically-named columns in the wide output. That's not a typically valid data.frame (i.e. what does `wide_df$TRCC1` refer to?). Is that intentional?

Comment: Correct--I edited the post appropriately.  The dataframe has 1000+ rows with on 23 unique IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to create a column that distinguishes between different observations of the same ID:

```
df |>
  mutate(row = row_number(), .by = ID) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = AJ_Vol)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
    row TRCC1 DNRC1 ILAC1
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  14.5  11.3  5.67
2     2  15.0  NA   NA
```

Assuming data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("TRCC1", "TRCC1", "DNRC1", "ILAC1"),
  AJ_Vol = c(14.454166, 14.976905, 11.344002, 5.673755)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp <- split(df$AJ_Vol, df$ID)
lapply(tmp, \(x) x[1:max(lengths(tmp))]) |> 
  data.frame()

#    DNRC1    ILAC1    TRCC1
# 1 11.344 5.673755 14.45417
# 2     NA       NA 14.97691
```

Reproducible data

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("TRCC1", "TRCC1", "DNRC1", "ILAC1"),
  AJ_Vol = c(14.454166, 14.976905, 11.344002, 5.673755)
)
```